# Why can i export the display from linux to linux?

Tags: centos, display

**local machine**

```
[mukesh@centos ~]$ xhost 192.168.4.200
192.168.4.200 being added to access control list
```

**remote VM machine**

```
[mukesh@centos ~]$ ssh user@192.168.4.200
user@192.168.4.200's password: 
Last login: Fri Jul  7 02:38:07 2017
[user@labipa ~]$ DISPLAY=192.168.1.3:0.0;export DISPLAY
[user@labipa ~]$ firefox
Error: cannot open display: 192.168.1.3:0.0
[user@labipa ~]$ su -
Password: 
Last login: Fri Jul  7 02:47:53 EDT 2017 on pts/1
[root@labipa ~]# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X11F
X11Forwarding yes
#   X11Forwarding no
```

Also, as per http://www.softpanorama.org/Xwindows/Troubleshooting/can_not_open_display.shtml on **remote machine**

```
[root@labipa ~]#  netstat -tulpen | grep "\(177\|6000\)"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          50364      1512/Xorg           
tcp6       0      0 :::6000                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          50363      1512/Xorg           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:177             0.0.0.0:*                           0          48805      1476/gdm     

contents of  /etc/gdm/custom.conf
[security]
DisallowTCP=false
[xdmcp]
Enable=true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If X11 forwarding is enabled *in both the client and the server*, `ssh` will automatically set up the `DISPLAY` variable (to a local proxy). You don't need to set it, and especially not directly to the machine's IP address; that will completely bypass the `ssh` mechanism. Use `echo $DISPLAY` to verify the display is set by `ssh`.

If you only enabled X11 forwarding on the server (as shown), and don't want to enable it generally, use `ssh -X` to also enable it in the client on a per-use base.

Comment: Thanks, just tried `ssh -X` it works. but without the X option how do i make it work. on client `X11Forwarding yes` is there in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I tried without exporting the DISPLAY variable this time but it didn't work.Is there any other change that i need to make.

Comment: `man ssh_config`. Note the missing `d`.